# Python ModuleNotFoundError for command line tools built with setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I am trying to build a simple command line tool and package it with `setup.py`. Here's my directory structure.

```
├── s3_md5
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── cmd.py
│   └── src
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── cli.py
│       ├── logger.py
│       ├── s3_file.py
│       └── s3_md5.py
├── setup.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── test_calculate_range_bytes_from_part_number.py
    ├── test_get_file_size.py
    ├── test_get_range_bytes.py
    └── test_parse_file_md5.py
```

In `setup.py`

```py
'''installer'''
from os import getenv

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="s3-md5",
    description="Get fast md5 hash from an s3 file",
    version=getenv('VERSION', '1.0.0'),
    url="https://github.com/sakibstark11/s3-md5-python",
    author="Sakib Alam",
    author_email="16sakib@gmail.com",
    license="MIT",
    install_requires=[
        "boto3==1.26.41",
        "boto3-stubs[s3]",
    ],
    extras_require={
        "develop": [
            "autopep8==2.0.1",
            "moto==4.0.12",
            "pytest==7.2.0",
            "pylint==3.1.0",
        ],
        "release": ["wheel==0.43.0"]
    },
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["test", "venv"]),
    python_requires=">=3.10.12",
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['s3-md5=s3_md5.cmd:run'],
    }
)
```

And `cmd.py`

```
'''driver'''
from time import perf_counter

from boto3 import client
from src.cli import parse_args
from src.logger import logger
from src.s3_md5 import parse_file_md5


def run():
// some stuff with imports from src


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

When I run the `cmd.py` from the `s3_md5` directory itself, everything is fine. But when I build and install it as a command line tool and try to run that, it throws

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I checked the lib folder and it does contain the src folder. Oddly enough when I use `s3_md5.src.cli` within `cmd.py`; the command line tool works but running the script from  the directory doesn't really work as it references the package installed not the code itself which causes issues for development usage.
I've tried reading everything I can about python module system but I can't wrap my head around to this. I suspect its to do with the PYTHONPATH not knowing where to look for `src` but I can be wrong. I tried using relative import which works for the command line tool but throws no known parent for directly running `python cmd.py`

Comment: `import s3_md5.src.cli` is the correct way to do it. If you want to run the script from the source tree you should do it from the directory containing the `s3_md5` directory.

Comment: Would you be able to explain why that's the correct way to do it please?

Comment: The biggest reason is that it works. And it's consistent with setup.py which says that the name of the package is "s3-md5", not "src".

Comment: When I run it as the command line, why doesn't python see the src folder? why does it think src is a separate thing? cause in the lib folder, I can see the src folder nested within the s3_md5 folder. Apologies if I'm asking silly question.

Comment: Because the package that is installed is `s3_md5` which has a subpackage `src`. So you need to import it as such.